# User Profile Synchronization Won't Update Profiles in SharePoint 2013

Tags: ad

OK, so just as the title suggests, I am not able to see changes made in AD reflect in my SharePoint 2013 environment. I have successfully created a User Profile Synchronization application (CA > Application Management > Manage service applications), and have started the User Profile Synchronization Service. I have also successfully created a connection, with filter (userAccountControl, Bit on equals, 2), and am able to view all my users in AD tree under the UPS Application > People > Manage User Profiles. The Farm account has been granted delegated control in AD to replicate directory changes.

Here is where it gets confusing. When changes are made in AD (disable user, change information), I am able to see these changes reporting in the Synchronization Service Manager (miisclient.exe) on the SharePoint server. For instance, if I disable a user, I can see "Deletes - 1" under Export Statistics, but the user account remains in SharePoint. On the same note, if I change a phone number in AD, I can see the change reported as an Update, but the information never updates in SharePoint.

Is there something that I am missing? What other tool or logs can I view to help me figure out why the SharePoint profiles aren't reflecting the changes made in AD?